# Vote To Close button does not work when placed over Company Job Ad

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, vote-to-close, advertising

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open the Close dialog on a question.
2. Position the "Vote to Close" button over the company logo in a job ad on the sidebar.
3. Press the "Vote to Close" button.

[image: Button overlapping job ad]

**Expected behavior:**

My close vote should be submitted successfully.

**Actual behavior:**

The company jobs page opens in a new tab, and my close vote is not registered.

The click event for the ad must be taking priority over the close button.  Reproduced on an ad for [Vantage Robotics](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/vantage-robotics).

---

Google Chrome Version 57.0.2987.98 (64-bit)

macOS Sierra Version 10.12.4 (16E195)

Adblock Plus Version 1.13.2

Comment: no-repro. Use uBlock.

Comment: @JanDvorak Does the ad show up at all with uBlock?  I'm still using ABP, and the ad appears.

Comment: Nope, no ads appear for me. Though I did have to add a cosmetic filter to get rid of the space left behind.

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 - Firefox 52 & AdBlock+/AdBlock+ Popup Blocker,  with a Pendo Job Ad shown.

Comment: That's my bad, fix going up shortly.

Comment: @rossipedia I can't wait to learn what caused it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: `z-index` is a royal pain :(

We had an issue with the "Learn more" button on Company Page Ads. While fixing that, I discovered that we were nesting `<a>` tags, which is kind of a "don't do that" thing and caused some weird issues with how the browser decided to render the ad.

Fixing that involved overlaying the `<a>` tags for the various parts of the ad using `z-index` and `position: absolute`. Unfortunately, I picked a bad `z-index` value that was *higher* than the one used for the Vote to Close overlay.

And since `z-index` is apparently global to the document, that meant that the CP ad `<a>` elements were rendered on top of the Vote To Close dialog and prevented interaction with the areas where they overlapped.

The fix was essentially: use a smaller `z-index` value. It is building out to Prod now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does Stack Overflow follow any kind of style guide re: `z-index`? e.g. 1, 10, 100, 200, 300, buttons should be in whole thousands and iterate by 5 up from that for other elements, etc.? Or is it just the Wild West of the Z Plane? :-)

Comment: It's a bit wild west, but we're working on getting things like that standardized